# Spotify Apps API Memory Leak

Tags: spotify

I'm building an app that lets users browse grids of artists based on tags. So they pick a tag, and see ~30 artists for that tag, and can quickly change tags and see new artists.

For each artist, I grab their top 5 tracks and put them in a temp playlist, which is displayed using the Track Player view (square art with a play button).

However, I am seeing massive memory leaks as the user browses from tag to tag. It appears that Spotify keeps all the old temp playlists in memory, despite the user browsing away from the page and the DOM being destroyed. Even if my app is closed completely, the playlists stay in memory (I know because if I note the temp playlist uri, i can still access it next time my app loads).

This doesn't seem right to me. Memory usage just keeps on increasing as the user views more pages. Of course, I THINK that the temp playlists are to blame, but it might be something else.

1) What is the protocol for releasing temp playlists? Can I destroy them manually if I know I don't need them any more?

2) Is there a more efficient way to do what I want (show a bunch of track players that are tied to temp playlists)?

Thanks

Peter